# Trying to copy specific files to specific folders, but there's a catch

Tags: linux, bash, unix, if-statement, nested-loops

I am trying to copy specific files to specific folders, but the file names are like, `Long_John_Silver`, `Miss_Havisham` and `Master_Pip` and the folder names are like `Long`, `Miss` and `Master`. 
So essentially I'm trying to copy the files to their respective folders e.g. Master_Pip.txt into the folder named Master.
And so what I've tried to do is to capture the first word of the file name and somehow use that as a reference, however, it is at this point that I falter.

```
for fldr in /home/playground/genomes* ; do

find . -name *fna.gz | while read f ; do

    f_name=$( echo $fldr | cut -d '/' -f 7 | cut -d '_' -f 1) ;

    #echo $f_name ;

    if [ "$f_name" == /home/playground/port/"$f_name" ]; then

        cp -r "$f" /home/playground/port/"$f_name"/ ;

    else

        continue    

    fi

done

done
```

edit-----------------------------------------------

```
for fldr in /home/p995824/scripts/playground/genomes_2/* ; do

find . -name *fna.gz | while read f ; do

    basenm=${fldr##*/} ; f_name=${basenm%%_*} ; 


    cp -r $f /home/p995824/scripts/playground/port/$f_name/ ;

done

done
```

This script copies all the files to all the folders. But I am struggling to construct a condition statement that will specific to which folder each file is copied to. I've tried the if statement as you can see, but I must be constructing it wrongly. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that I was copying all the files into all the folders based on the type of file i.e. .fna.gz, so I specified what type of fna.gz file I want to be read and then copied. There was no need for an if statement since the specificity is implied through the parameter expansion. It now works perfectly.

```
for fldr in /home/scripts/playground/genomes_2/* ; do

basenm=${fldr##*/} ; f_name=${basenm%%_*} ; 

find . -name $f_name*fna.gz | while read f ; do

    cp -r $f /home/scripts/playground/port/$f_name/ ;



done

done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your comparison `if [ "$f_name" == /home/playground/port/"$f_name" ]` is incorrect. `$f_name` is the prefix of the filename and you comparing it to a full path.

Try this:

```
for fldr in /home/playground/genomes* ; do

find . -name *fna.gz | while read f ; do

    # basename will truncate the path leaving only the filename
    f_name=$( basename ${fldr} | cut -d'_' -f1) ;

    # $f_name is the filename prefix "Long", "Master", etc

    # if the directory exists (-d)
    if [ -d "/home/playground/port/$f_name" ]; then

        # I don't think you need (-r) here if you're just copying a single file
        cp "$f" "/home/playground/port/$f_name/" ;

    else

        continue    

    fi

done

done
```

Comment: This didn't copy the files. 
I just wonder whether the file is actually captured in the `$f` variable or not.

Comment: What does `echo $f` reveal?

Comment: It reveals the full path directory of the file (.fna.gz).

Comment: Hmm weird and you can't pass that to `cp`? Try put a few more `echo` statements in there and see if the  commands are correct after substituting the variables. I don't have a bash shell at the moment.

Comment: I removed the if statement and it copied all the files into all the folders so I can confirm that the `$f` variable does carry the files. 
Where I'm going wrong is in the `if statement`.

Comment: Does the directory exist? Maybe you need to create the directory first. Is the `if` statement meaningful? What should it be checking for?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
for fldr in  `find /tmp/playground/  -type f` 
do 
    NAME=`basename $fldr | cut -d_ -f1`
    DEST=/tmp/playground/$NAME
    if [ -d "$DEST" ]  
    then
        cp $fldr $DEST
    fi 
done
```

Comment: I have replicated the scenario described in your question and tested it. It works as expected. Can you give me more details about what didn't work for you?

Comment: Ah, okay Maybe it was a syntax error on my part but I've managed to resolve the problem in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do from the other way round? Search files matching the folder name and copy them instead of searching for folders from the first word of the filename. I maybe wrong though.. :)

```
for folder_name in /home/playground/port/*
do
    cp /home/playground/folder_name* $folder_name
done
```